# Injective Function Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If $|A| = 5$ and $ |B| =25$ , how many functions from $A$ to $B$ are injective?

I'm not quite sure how to tackle this problem as I do not quite understand what $|A| = 5$ and $|B| = 25$ means .

Comment: $|A|=5$ means $A$ is a set with $5$ elements.

Comment: $|A|$ is a common notation for the number of elements in the set $|A|$.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of injective maps from $A$ to $B$ is $n!\times \binom{m}{n}$ with $m = |B|, n = |A|$. In your case, it's $5!\times \binom{25}{5}$.

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot!

Comment: @Charlie: Also you can try to find how many surjective maps from $A$ to $B$ with $|A| = 5, |B| = 3$, say.

Answer (score 0):

To each elements in A, we associate a unique elements in B, there are $25$ choices for what $1$ gets map to, then $24$ choice for what $2$ gets map to and so on. So $25*24*23*22*21=6 375 600$.